# Calculating the error in the resolving time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

In a Geiger counter experiment, I am asked to calculate the error in the resolving time and what I have is the resolving time from the formula 
$$T_r = \frac{(R_1+R_2-R_{12})}{(2R_1R_2)}$$

where $R_1$ is the count rate for the right half of the source, $R_2$ is the count rate for the left half of the source and $R_{12}$ is the count rate for both right and left halfs . And I also have the true count rate which I got from the formula $\displaystyle{R= \frac{R_o}{(1-R_oT_r)}}$

So any hint how to get the error in the resolving time ? Thank you in advance [image: snapshot of the problem]

Comment: Care must be taken in finding the error in $T_R$ because as you have written the equation the same variables appear in the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should consider the measured rates to be independent Poisson-distributed variables, meaning that their standard deviation scales with $\sqrt{N}$ where $N$ is the number of observed counts.

Then use the normal equations for combining errors when adding / dividing quantities.

**UPDATE** as @Farcher pointed out, there is a correlation between values in the numerator and denominator; you can avoid this by simply rewriting your expression as

$$T_R = \frac12\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}-\frac{R_{12}}{R_1 R_2}\right)$$

in which case you no longer have correlated errors in your expression.

Comment: @ maryam Care must be taken in finding the error in $T_R$ because as you have written the equation the same variables appear in the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: Thanx alot!! But I am not sure how to calculate the standard deviation what I did is   take the count rates values and calculate their standard devation and I got 26891.7 is this a correct way??and by the observed is it the total of the count rate?? Sorry but one last thing I don't understand what you mean by using the normal equation for combining errors?? I apologize for any trouble...

Comment: @Farcher - good point. To avoid this, write the expression in terms that don't have correlated values. I edited my answer.

Comment: When I say "the normal equation" I mean: the usual way to combine errors: if I have $A+B$ with errors $dA$ and $dB$, then the error in the sum is $\sqrt{dA^2+dB^2}$. For fractions, there are other expressions. Standard propagation of errors stuff. As for the count rate standard deviation - I really can't tell from your comment what you did, and therefore cannot comment on whether this "is a correct way". I stated "the square root of the number of counts is the standard deviation". If that is what you did, you did it right; if not, then not.